# How to traverse a RDD efficiently

Tags: scala, traversal, rdd

For example, I have a Scala `RDD` with 10000 elements, I want to take each element one by one to deal with. How do I do that? I tried use `take(i).drop(i-1)`, but it is extraordinarily time consuming.

Comment: Why don't you just use `map` on your `RDD` or `foreach` ?

Comment: I use scala. For exeampe, my rdd type is org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, String, String, String)])] , I just want to get every element then do some other processing.

Comment: You want to iterate over `Tuple(String, Iterable[(String, String, String, String)])` or over your `Iterable` ?

Comment: First take every tuple, then get the Iterable in the Tuple.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you said in the comments:

```
yourRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2.map(elem => doSomething(elem)))
```

The first `map` will iterate over the tuples inside of your `RDD`, that is why I called the variable `tuple`, then for every `tuple` we get the second element `._2` and apply a `map` which iterate over all the elements of your `Iterable` that is why I called the variable `elem`.
`doSomething()` is just a random function of your choice to apply on each element.